# how do migrate and rollback work in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When we call

```
bundle exec db:migrate
```

Does it always create a new table? Or just create new columns that are not in the previous table?

And what does rollback do? How does it know which column to delete and is this deleting thing reversible? For example, if I accidentally deleted a useful column, can I cancel the previous action and get it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean, `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

1. Active Record tracks which migrations have already been run. Example: If you are using sqlite3 as Database you can look at the table - `schema_migrations` which has these migration details. It mostly has entries like

   > ```
   >  row id          version
   >     1            "20120926105202" #matched migration timestamp
   > ```
2. This rake task just runs what you have in the migration files under `<app>/db/migrate/`.
   So, if you have creation of tables in that migration file, it would do that.
3. To Rollback the last migration you can always run `rake db:rollback`
4. For a better understanding, I request you to read this [Guide on Rails Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#writing-a-migration). Reading through it would resolve all your queries w.r.t migrations.

Comment: For example, if I have a description column with useful data, and I deleted them. When I roll back, does it only recreate the deleted column without the old data?

Comment: @user1229490 if you rollback you are _undoing_ the migration. So if you had created the table in last migration it would go away. Now, if you again run db:migrate - it will recreate the table with this column.

Comment: So the previous data would still be there?

Comment: How would it be if you deleted?

Comment: OK I see. I thought Rails tracked everything and it was possible to retrieve the deleted data...

Answer (score 0):

You're describing what to do by yourself.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up # for rake db:migrate
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down # for rake db:rollback
    drop_table :products
  end
end
```